# Add data to database from VB program -> safe way?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have developed a little VB program. I want the user to have the option to submit certain usage statistics/data (like some basic info about their system etc) to me. I want this data to end up in MySql db, so I can create queries/reports.
But what is the best/safest way to accomplish this? Of course, I could use the MySQL client, and just insert the data in the database. But is this a safe way? Using reverse engineering tools you could easily discover the database credentials, and add rubbish to the database (of course I would create a user that only can do inserts).
So, what would be a good approach for this?

Thanks

Comment: You could use a web service, just pass the data to your service from the client. All the DB Authentication is on your web service, so safely away from users system.

Comment: Since I have absolute no idea how to create a webservice, I googled around a bit.
I believe I should create a SOAP server, and then use wsdl to connect my .net app to it?

Comment: I tried this tutorial: w3programmers.com/soap-with-php-and-mysql. I was able to setup a server, and added the service reference, but I can't get data from the database. Any good tutorials on this? To build in security (I don't want anyone to execute commands), I just add something like

    > if ($key == "somekey") { 
> // Execute code 
> } 
> else 
> { 
> die();
> } 

And pass the key when doing a request from my app?
PS: Sorry, I can't figure out how I put the code between code tags

Comment: Grab a free trial at http://www.pluralsight.com and take a look at WCF, WebAPI or SOAP Web Services from there. Great step by step videos.

Comment: @mitch2k Don't get bogged down by the terminology.  Your solution could be as simple as an HTTP server (with a page) that accepts POST data with just about any kind of server side processing.  The server side processing then forwards the post data on to the DB.  Simple as that.  (The only difficulty might be authenticating the client, SSL is a start down that road but you're still safer than the full DB access that a MySQL client would expose)

Answer (score -1):

I think store-procedure is good solution.
link must use with class w

Comment: Mousa, you might consider rewriting this answer to include more information and references as to why you think a stored procedure is the best solution.